# Error in precision of python math.log(x,base) result

Tags: python, python-3.x, logarithm, exponent

Python math.log(x,base) functionality is giving a minute error in the result which is breaking my functionality. I am trying to solve a problem where I need to get the index till which a number can go such that it is less than the defined boundary

i.e., For `a**i < boundary` I want to know maximum possible value of 'i' where 'a' and 'boundary' are provided as inputs. `i` and 'a` are whole numbers

To get maximum value of i, I wrote the below logic:

```
max_i = int(math.log(boundary-1,a))
```

This logic is failing for multiple cases. e.g: `a = 56` and `boundary = 175617`, `max_i` should be 3 because `56**3` (56 raised to power of 3) is 175616 (which is 1 less than given boundary). Below is proof for the same

```
>>> math.log(175616,56)
2.9999999999999996 
>>> 56**3 
175616
```

Because of this minute difference `max_i` becomes 2 instead of 3. What would resolve this precision issue? I tried converting a and boundary to floats as suggested in some forum but that doesn't seem to change the result

Edit: Apologies, I forgot to mention that I already wrote a quick fix with something similar to what Thierry commented. I am checking if there is a way to get rid of floating point operations by proposing a fix at package level

Comment: You are bound to encounter such problems with floats, as they have limited precision, so you have to take this into account; You could for example check for `boundary` instead of `boundary-1`, and check that the `max_i` you find this way isn't too large by calculating `a**max_i` .

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I did add this as a quick fix in my code, which is avoiding from breaking the functionality and sorry for not mentioning the same in my question. Is there no other way to fix this?

Comment: you use can `math.ceil()`?

Comment: @nobleknight that will solve only this case and will fail rest all normal cases, please check the problem statement again

Comment: then use `round()`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a quick hack that fixes the problem, you can just add an additional check in there:

```
if base**(max_i+1) <= limit:
    max_i = max_i + 1
```

This simply checks whether a number one larger than your integer value would also fulfill the condition, and if it does, replaces the initial value. Handily gets rid of this floating point error :)

Comment: Thank you, I have already implemented a quick fix similar to the one commented by @Thierry. Please do let me know if you get an idea of a solution to resolve without additional hacks

Comment: If you have a different solution that you have adopted, please add your solution as an answer and accept the appropriate answer so we can all learn from the collective wisdom.